# Is there a term/name for these labels?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, terminology, labels

Are there any conventional names for these informational labels?

[image: Here's the link]

Comment: Sure thing. Based on the kind of answers it's getting, this question might be better suited for the graphic design site. (Don't repost the question, though. I'll migrate the questions and answers together if there are no objections.)

Comment: I'm fine with that :)

Answer (score 12):

I don't know of any generally accepted word for them, but if we are going to keep to the **closest analogy in English** they would be:

**Sash** - when it is shown as a piece of fabric across or around an item.

[image]

**Ribbon** - when the end of the ribbon is shown.  Many awards are given in this way and they are almost always called ribbons.

[image]

Comment: A note of caution about using Ribbon though; as Microsoft may have beaten you to it with their Office Ribbon UI.

Answer (score 4):

They're all different types of Ribbon. The first one is a wrapping ribbon and the second one is a hanging ribbon. You also find the banner ribbon a lot if you just purely search for 'ribbon'. This [ribbon pack is from Code Canyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/css3-ribbon-pack/851059).

[image]

Comment: Nice that you also provided the link for the pack of ribbons! :)

Answer (score 2):

I call it **ribbon**, but I am not aware of an "official" name.

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons) calls them ribbons.

Answer (score 2):

We used to call them a "flash", which was confusing when compared to Adobe flash. It was used for any sort of addition to an image like "sale", "new in" or whatever. It was used irrespective of the style ( the term "sash" implies a particular style, but some clients used strips across the bottom or top or anywhere ).

Answer (score 0):

Good question :) struggled with the same problem when I tried to communicate this to a graphics designer.  Ended up just sending a link to an image...

"corner banner"?

Comment: Haha! So true. I know Themeforest calls it a "sash". Maybe we could think of a name for it.

Comment: I like "Sash", I must admit I've seen these more than a few times and never known what to call them.

Answer (score -1):

I call these labels **tags**. Simply.

Comment: If you could elaborate a little and maybe come up with some proof of your answer, it would provide more value to the OP and others reading your answer in the future!

Comment: If you google Corner Ribbon and Corner Tags, you'd see that results for corner ribbon are somewhat more accurate. Do you have any references?

Comment: I've heard them refered to as ribbons most often. I think tags could too easily be confused with tags in code, or the code tag of whatever you're pointing to.